# Michelson interferometer: beam splitter affects amplituedes?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, interference, interferometry

Let's suppose an initial plane wave $\vec{E}=\vec{E_0}e^{i(\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}-\omega t)}$ enters a Michelson interferometer . Let $\vec{E_1}=\vec{E_{01}}e^{i(kz-\omega t)}$ and $\vec{E_2}=\vec{E_{02}}e^{i(kz+kd-\omega t)}$ , be the output beams that hit the detector. Here $d$ is the difference in the distances of the plane mirrors from the beamsplitter. To proceed my textbook assumes: $$\vec{E_{01}}=\vec{E_{02}}.$$ Why is this the case? Is this only true under the hypothesis that the starting beam is linearly polarized under some particular direction? What is the relationship between $\vec{E_{01}}$,$\vec{E_{02}}$ and $\vec{E_{0}}$ ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your book probably assumes the conceptually simple case: a perfect 50/50 beamsplitter and ideal mirrors on each arm of the interferometer. In reality, these will not be perfect, but it's a decent approximation. Let's say, in real life, the reflected and transmitted beam amplitudes are not quite equal; i.e. $RE_0 \ne TE_0$, but the mirrors are basically perfect (not hard to achieve). Well by the time each split beam reaches the recombined beam, it has transmitted once and reflected once, giving a total amplitude of $E_1=E_2=RTE_0$. Of course, if the interferometer arms have unequal loss, then all bets are off, and in practice you won't get perfect interference. That said, you'd never get perfect interference anyway since it also depends on alignment, diffraction, propagation loss, etc.